# Unique property in Mongoose + Node JS doesn't work - keeps creating new documents with the same property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider the Schema :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            maxlength: 32,
            unique: true
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
```

And the `create` controller function :

```
const Category = require('../models/category');
// const Product = require('../models/product');
const { errorHandler } = require('../helpers/dbErrorHandler');

exports.create = (req, res) => {
    const category = new Category(req.body);
    category.save((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: errorHandler(err)
            });
        }
        res.json({ data });
    });
};
```

With the route :

```
const { create } = require('../controllers/category');
router.post('/category/create/:userId', create);
```

Whenever I create a new `name` and reenter the same `name` I get no exception even though it's declared in the Schema that `unique: true`.

Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no unique index on the collection,

either create one manually or add below in options of the connection string

```
const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  autoIndex: true, //this is the code I added that solved it all
  keepAlive: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}

db.connect(process.env.DB_URI, options)
  .then(() => console.log('connected to DB'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```